# Resample xarray Dataset to annual frequency using only winter data

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a dataset which consists of daily x,y gridded meteorological data for several years. I am interested in calculating annual means of winter data only, ie. not including the summer data as well.

I think that I need to use the `resample` command with, e.g. a frequency of `AS-OCT` to resample the time series to annual frequency with winter beginning in October each year (it's northern latitudes).

What I can't work out is how to specify that I only want to use data from months October through April/May, ignoring June, July and August.

As the resample function works with `ndarray` objects I came up with a fairly unportable way of doing this for a sum:

```
def winter(x,axis):
    # Only use data from 1 October to end of April (day 211)
    return np.sum(x[0:211,:,:],axis=0)
win_sum = all_data.resample('AS-OCT',how=winter,dim='TIME')
```

but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Python does not have a resample function.  If you are using Pandas, add the tag to your question.

Comment: This question is about an xarray Dataset rather than a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Have you tried masking (with `.where`) and then resampling? I think you'll find that much easier than trying to combine the masking into the resample. If you have a fully repro example I can respond with an example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to create a mask for the dates you wish to exclude. You can do this by using groupby to extract the month.

```python
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some example data at daily resolution that also has a space dimension
time = pd.date_range('01-01-2000','01-01-2020')
space = np.arange(0,100)
data = np.random.rand(len(time), len(space))
da = xr.DataArray(data, dims=['time','space'], coords={'time': time, 'space': space})
# this is the trick -- use groupby to extract the month number of each day
month = da.groupby('time.month').apply(lambda x: x).month
# create a boolen Dataaray that is true only during winter
winter = (month <= 4) | (month >= 10)
# mask the values not in winter and resample annualy starting in october
da_winter_annmean = da.where(winter).resample('AS-Oct', 'time')
```

Hopefully this works for you. It is slightly more elegant, but the groupby trick still feels kind of hackish. Maybe there is still a better way.

Comment: the trick to extract the month of number of each data point is very useful for any sorts of slicing and filtering.